# What are different types of test doubles and their uses?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, tdd

I was going through an online course on test driven development and came across the concept of test doubles. As per the definition of test double in the course :

> **Test Doubles** : Test doubles are objects that are used in unit tests as replacement to the real production system collaborators.

I got an idea what test doubles mean. But then it was mentioned there are various types of test doubles. The ones mentioned in the course were :

> **Dummy** : Objects that can be passed around as necessary but do not have any type of test implementation and should never be used.
>
> **Fake** : These objects generally have a simplified functional implementation of a particular interface that is adequate for testing
> but not for production.
>
> **Stub** : These objects provide implementation with canned answers that are suitable for the tests.
>
> **Spies** : These objects provide implementation that record the values that were passed in so they can be used by the tests.
>
> **Mocks** : These objects are pre-programmed to expect specific calls and parameters and can throw exceptions when necessary.

I have worked with mocks before and do have a brief idea of what they are and how to use them. Though I was confused regarding the other mentioned types of test doubles.

Can someone help me with difference between these types of test doubles and when to use one ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Useful literature,

- from Martin Fowler:

  - [TestDouble](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html)
  - [Mocks Aren't Stubs](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)
- from Sandi Metz:

  - [Magic Tricks of Testing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M)

---

Dummy is sort of an odd case, in that you are using a dummy because the code under test doesn't actually use the dummy; in other words, the composition of the system is requiring you to supply some superfluous elements.  Often, this is a hint that the logic you are testing should be accessible via a more specific interface.

Stubs and Fakes are typically used when a test scenario requires that the code under test obtains values from some dependency.

A stub is very focused; it doesn't pretend to do the right thing internally, but instead just returns some canned answer.  For instance, you might use a stub to mimic a specific failure mode.

Fake is badly named - it's a real implementation of the dependency, just one that is optimized for testing (small, deterministic, in memory) rather than optimized for production (scale).  In some circles, you'll hear [substitute](https://github.com/eventide-project/useful-objects#substitutes), rather than "fake".

Spies and mocks are typically used when you are trying to determine that your code sends the right information to a dependency, without the costs of being coupled to that dependency.

Spies normally maintain a history of messages that they receive during testing, which can later be verified against an expected message list.  Mocks are a more active expression of that idea, where assertions are made about the behavior of the code under test while the scenario is running, rather than afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the short read of Uncle Bob's blog article ***"The Little Mocker"*** which not only provides a good explanation ot the difference types of *test doubles* and distinction between those types but also *explains what type to use for what situation* illustrated with easy to understand *code samples*.

See: https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2014/05/14/TheLittleMocker.html