# JavaScript Testing spy-spies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd, end-to-end

In js testing, I can't understand the concept of Spy- Spies and the difference with stubs.

spy-spies:

```
function spyOn(Object, method) { /*... */ }

// A common way of using a spy
const dateSpy = spyOn(Date, 'now')

Date.now()

// A common way of checking the spy
console.log(dateSpy.called.length > 0)
```

stubs:

```
function stubAmount(amount) {
  Apple.amount = () => amount
}

// Testing function
function haveApple(amount) {
  stubAmount(amount)
  howsMyCollection()
}
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63163451/7730554

Answer (score 0):

**When to Use Spies**

As the name might suggest, spies are used to get information about function calls. For example, a spy can tell us how many times a function was called, what arguments each call had, what values were returned, what errors were thrown, etc.

As such, a spy is a good choice whenever the goal of a test is to verify something happened. Combined with Sinon’s assertions, we can check many different results by using a simple spy.

The most common scenarios with spies involve…

- Checking how many times a function was called
- Checking what arguments were passed to a function

**When to Use Stubs**

Stubs are like spies, except in that they replace the target function. They can also contain custom behavior, such as returning values or throwing exceptions. They can even automatically call any callback functions provided as parameters.

Stubs have a few common uses:

- You can use them to replace problematic pieces of code
- You can use them to trigger code paths that wouldn’t otherwise trigger – such as error handling
- You can use them to help test asynchronous code more easily